# Does this break my fast?

Tags: sawm, sick

I suffer from allergies and a runny nose often, and when I’m fasting, I sometimes sniff when I feel it (nasal drainage) coming down my nose, or I just blow my nose. Other times, I feel it go down to my throat from my nose by itself and I have no choice but to swallow it sometimes and coughing to spit it out can be difficult. Does this break my fast

Answer (score 0):

There are differing opinions regarding opinions among the scholars regarding this fact. The correct view is however, that it doesn't invalidate your fast, since it does not fall under the heading of food and drink.
According to Shaykh Ibn 'Uthmayeen (May Allah be Pleased with him) , in the case of different opinions, Holy Quran and Sunnah are the reference points. Now since, in Quran it is not mentioned to be breaking the fast. Thus, swallowing the mucus will not invalidate the fast. But we should try not to swallow it and try to cough it out.
Jazakallah Khairan.